# ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, concurrency, dictionary

### Introduction

I'm building an API wrapper for the [SE API 2.0](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)
Currently, I'm implementing a cache feature, this wasn't an issue until now. Now I'm taking concurrency into account. This would be my test method:

#### Code

```
public static void TestConcurrency()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    IList<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(p => client.GetAnswers(), null));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("elapsed: {0}", sw.Elapsed.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

### Description

Internally, the client has a `RequestHandler` class, which attempts to fetch a value from the cache, and if it fails to do so, it performs the actual request.

#### Code

```
/// <summary>
/// Checks the cache and then performs the actual request, if required.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The strong type of the expected API result against which to deserialize JSON.</typeparam>
/// <param name="endpoint">The API endpoint to query.</param>
/// <returns>The API response object.</returns>
private IApiResponse<T> InternalProcessing<T>(string endpoint) where T : class
{
    IApiResponse<T> result = FetchFromCache<T>(endpoint);
    return result ?? PerformRequest<T>(endpoint);
}
```

### Description

The code that actually performs the request is irrelevant to this issue. The code that attempts to access the cache does the following:

#### Code

```
/// <summary>
/// Attempts to fetch the response object from the cache instead of directly from the API.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The strong type of the expected API result against which to deserialize JSON.</typeparam>
/// <param name="endpoint">The API endpoint to query.</param>
/// <returns>The API response object.</returns>
private IApiResponse<T> FetchFromCache<T>(string endpoint) where T : class
{
    IApiResponseCacheItem<T> cacheItem = Store.Get<T>(endpoint);
    if (cacheItem != null)
    {
        IApiResponse<T> result = cacheItem.Response;
        result.Source = ResultSourceEnum.Cache;
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

#### Description

The actual implementation of the cache store works on a `ConcurrentDictionary`, when the `Get<T>()` method is invoked, I:

- Check whether the dictionary has an entry for `endpoint`.
- If it does, I verify whether or not it holds a response object.
- If it doesn't already have a response object, the cache item's state will be `Processing`, and the thread will be put to sleep for a small amount of time, waiting on the actual request being completed.
- Once or if the response is "commited" to the cache store (this happens once the request is completed), the cache item is returned.
- If the cache item was too old or the request processing timed out, the entry is removed from the store.
- If the cache didn't have an entry for `endpoint`, `null` is pushed into the cache as the response for `endpoint`, signaling a request on that endpoint is being processed and there is no need to issue more requests on the same endpoint. Then `null` is returned, signaling an actual request should be made.

#### Code

```
/// <summary>
/// Attempts to access the internal cache and retrieve a response cache item without querying the API.
/// <para>If the endpoint is not present in the cache yet, null is returned, but the endpoint is added to the cache.</para>
/// <para>If the endpoint is present, it means the request is being processed. In this case we will wait on the processing to end before returning a result.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The strong type of the expected API result.</typeparam>
/// <param name="endpoint">The API endpoint</param>
/// <returns>Returns an API response cache item if successful, null otherwise.</returns>
public IApiResponseCacheItem<T> Get<T>(string endpoint) where T : class
{
    IApiResponseCacheItem cacheItem;
    if (Cache.TryGetValue(endpoint, out cacheItem))
    {
        while (cacheItem.IsFresh && cacheItem.State == CacheItemStateEnum.Processing)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
        if (cacheItem.IsFresh && cacheItem.State == CacheItemStateEnum.Cached)
        {
            return (IApiResponseCacheItem<T>)cacheItem;
        }
        IApiResponseCacheItem value;
        Cache.TryRemove(endpoint, out value);
    }
    Push<T>(endpoint, null);
    return null;
}
```

The issue is indeterminately, sometimes two requests make it through, instead of just one like it is designed to happen.

I'm thinking somewhere along the way something that's not thread safe is being accessed. But I can't identify what that might be. What could it be, or how should I debug this properly?

## Update

The issue was I wasn't *always* being thread safe on the `ConcurrentDictionary`

This method wasn't retuning a `boolean` indicating whether the cache was successfully updated, therefore if this method failed, `null` would have been returned twice by `Get<T>()`.

#### Code

```
/// <summary>
/// Attempts to push API responses into the cache store.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The strong type of the expected API result.</typeparam>
/// <param name="endpoint">The queried API endpoint.</param>
/// <param name="response">The API response.</param>
/// <returns>True if the operation was successful, false otherwise.</returns>
public bool Push<T>(string endpoint, IApiResponse<T> response) where T : class
{
    if (endpoint.NullOrEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    IApiResponseCacheItem item;
    if (Cache.TryGetValue(endpoint, out item))
    {
        ((IApiResponseCacheItem<T>)item).UpdateResponse(response);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        item = new ApiResponseCacheItem<T>(response);
        return Cache.TryAdd(endpoint, item);
    }
}
```

### Description

The solution was to implement the return value, and changing `Get<T>()` adding this:

#### Code

```
if (Push<T>(endpoint, null) || retries > 1) // max retries for sanity.
{
    return null;
}
else
{
    return Get<T>(endpoint, ++retries); // retry push.
}
```

Comment: the apporach you show is not reentrancy-safe which leads to what you describe... being reentrancy-safe is something different from being thread-safe...

Comment: how would I turn my approach into something reentrance-safe like you suggest?

Comment: basically you need to implement a way to detect that and decide what exactly needs to happen when some reentrancy occurs - stall it till the current run is finished, discard it, process in parallel... any of these options may have sideefects - which again depend on your use cases/goals which are not very clear to me right now

Comment: that's what the code is supposed to be doing, on the first run it makes the request and signals that subsequent runs should wait on the request to complete.

Comment: from what I see your approach doesn't detect reentrancy cases - at least not reliably... since you are not checking for reentrancy but for some cache item... checking for reentrancy is like a "sentinel" on the entry of a method... your check is not taking into account the case where the same method is entered more than once in parallel for the same endpoint...

Comment: Yahia, you were spot on! Please post this as an answer so I can mark it as accepted. The issue was I wasn't making sure `Push<T>` succeded on adding the cache item to the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IApiResponseCacheItem<T> cacheItem = Store.Get<T>(endpoint);
if (cacheItem != null)
{
   // etc..
}
```

A ConcurrentDirectionary is thread-safe but that doesn't automatically make your code thread safe.  The above snippet is the core of the problem.  Two threads could call the Get() method at the same time and get a null.  They'll both continue on and call PerformRequest() concurrently.  You'll need to merge the InternalProcessing() and FetchFromCache() and ensure that only one thread can call PerformRequest by using a lock.  That might produce poor concurrency, perhaps you could just drop a duplicate response.  In all likelihood, the requests get serialized by the SE server anyway so it probably doesn't matter.